# NPM package - add a script to the consumer's node_modules/.bin

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm crafting a npm package.

**I want to expose a script to the consumer as soon as the package is installed**, much like Typescript's `tsc`.

How do I do it?

Comment: You mean your package can be used standalone also? like maybe the global packages `nodemon` or `http-server` etc etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something similar as below to your package.json:

```
  "bin": {
    "router": "dist/src/bin/router.js"
  }
```

This will create a symlink named router in the bin folder pointing to router.js.

Read more about bin [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin)